# postgres column auto update from parent

Tags: postgresql

Say I create a table like this:

```
create table mynode(id integer generated always as identity);
```

Now I create another table like this:

```
create table mybranch(parent integer references mynode(id) not null, owner integer references mynode(id) not null) inherits(mynode);
```

So now any branch in the `mybranch` table will have in its `parent` column a reference to either a `mynode` or `mybranch` row. It will also have an `owner`.

I'd like a way for a `mybranch` row's owner to automatically be the owner of its parent, or id of its parent if its parent is a `mynode`. This way, if a branch's ownership is changed, all its children's would be as well.

Alternately the `owner` column could be in the `mynode` table if that made it easier.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: have you found the solution?
im thinking of control it from backend if it is not possible from database.

Comment: I never figured out how to do it. I actually moved away from this approach, so I didn't really follow up on it. Sorry I'm not much help!

Comment: its ok.
already found the solution. someone replied to my post in another post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62043396/how-to-auto-update-column-value-in-child-table-based-on-parent-table